# Angular 2, enlaces

Tags: angularjs-2.0, scroll, ngroute

Tengo una web en angular 2, con las rutas puestas para que pueda ir navegando por la web cargando mis diferentes módulos, al hacer click en un enlace se me carga el modulo que quiero pero se me mantiene la posición del scroll.

Y necesito que cada vez que alguien haga click en un enlace, el modulo cargado se muestra desde arriba igual que cuando le das a un enlace normal en html que se carga la pagina desde arriba y la posición del scroll esta arriba.

Comment: Hola te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask] y al [tour]. Deberías facilitarnos lo que has intentado, el código que tienes, los errores que muestra. Facilita el trabajo a la comunidad mejorando tu pregunta.

Comment: Puedes subir alguna imagen para evidenciar lo que realmente quieres?, y tambien puedes aportar parte de tu codigo para una explicacion mas detallada.

Answer (score 1):

En el componente que definas tu enrutador debes de estar a la escucha del evento activate para hacer el scrollTop.

```
@Component({
  template: '<router-outlet
               (activate)="onActivate($event, outlet)" #outlet>
            </router-outlet>',
})
export class TuComponente {
  onActivate(e, outlet){
    outlet.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```